# Getting "Cannot resolve the OData request URL." for specific users on REST item update call

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I getting the "Cannot resolve the OData request URL." when making call like this:
PATCH https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users('user@domain.com')/messages/this-long-item-id

Problem that actually works only for user for which i provided explicit consent earlier. For two other users i can't provide individual consent because i updated the app to use the one-time administrative consent with permissions "allow read all mailboxes in organization" and "allow write all emails in organization" or such.
These permissions are listed in Azure AD as well.

What i can do to make my app working for all current and any future users?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I decoded the token and it has the following fieds:

```
{
  "aud": "https://outlook.office365.com/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/OBSCURED/",
  "iat": 1423163270,
  "nbf": 1423163270,
  "exp": 1423167170,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "tid": "OBSCURED",
  "roles": [
       "Mail.Write",
       "Mail.Read"
  ],
  "oid": "OBSCURED",
  "sub": "OBSCURED",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/OBSCURED/",
  "appid": "OBSCURED",
  "appidacr": "2"
}
```

**UPDATE**

I getting this error even if I use OutlookServiceClient class, since it builds the same query URI with correct API endpoint (with version number) specified.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [checking your access token](https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/ValidatingYourToken.md). It sounds like you might be getting a user token rather than an app token. If you parse the token and see user information (name, email address, etc) then you don't have an app-only token. Make sure you're doing the client credential auth flow rather than the code grant flow.

Also make sure that you are doing a one-time administrative consent experience. Your app should be having the admin go to a URL like:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&nonce=1a4a3fb8-9ede-4db8-a4e6-7b4e6b2e1ba4&response_mode=form_post&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code+id_token&prompt=admin_consent&redirect_uri=<YOUR APP REDIRECT>&resource=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2F
```

Note the `prompt=admin_consent` parameter.

Comment: I cooking the token this way, using ADAL library:

result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                    GetResourceUrl(),
                    new ClientAssertionCertificate(GetClientId(), AppCertificateHelper.GetCertificate())
                );

Comment: Can be this issue is cause of my current problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456278/retrieving-an-access-token-with-admin-consent-how-access-the-data-of-all-the-u?rq=1

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Since you mentioned that you had done individual consent earlier and then changed to client credential flow, I wanted to make sure that you've actually done an admin consent experience at least once to get admin consent recorded in Azure.

Comment: Yeah, i did that, but that did not helped.
Actually i had to give up on the project.
Actually this is not a professional behavior to disappear during project without giving any explanations, but it seems this project is beyond my skills barrier anyway, ad there was some other issues why i had to gave up away from project...

Comment: Sorry to hear that Konstantin. If you do decide to revisit, I'd highly recommend getting Matthias' sample .NET web app from https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-as-apponly-webapp or my sample Python web app from https://github.com/jasonjoh/python_clientcred and see if that helps.