# Error 404 trying to get message using OutlookServicesClient clas

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

Here is the following code snippet that fails with an exception about response with the status code 404:

```
            var client = new Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices
                .OutlookServicesClient(GetAPIEndpointUri(), 
                GetOrPrepareApplicationAccessTokenAsync
                );
            var messageFetcher = client.Users[mailbox].Messages.GetById(itemId);
            var message = await messageFetcher.ExecuteAsync();
            message.Subject = subject;
            await message.UpdateAsync();
```

Actually the following line fails:

```
            var message = await messageFetcher.ExecuteAsync();
```

Reviewed the query URI in the exception details and it looks like so:

https://outlook.office365.com/api/Users('mailbox%40domain.onmicrosoft.com')/Messages('long message id')

How the access token is obtained:

```
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
            GetAuthorityUrl()
            .ToString()
        );

        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                GetResourceUrl(),
                new ClientAssertionCertificate(GetClientId(), AppCertificateHelper.GetCertificate())
            );
```

Error information as it transformed to client side:

```
 {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"An error occurred while processing this request.","exceptionType":"Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException","stackTrace":"   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass12`2.<ExecuteSingleAsync>b__10(IAsyncResult i)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<ExecuteSingleAsync>d__14`2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.MessageFetcher.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at [[my code]]\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at [[My code]]","innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"NotFound","exceptionType":"Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException","stackTrace":"   at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)"}}
```

Exception details copied from VS exception asisstant:

```
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An error occurred while processing this request.
  Source=Microsoft.OData.Client
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass12`2.<ExecuteSingleAsync>b__10(IAsyncResult i)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<ExecuteSingleAsync>d__14`2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.MessageFetcher.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at [[My code]]
  InnerException: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=NotFound
       Source=Microsoft.OData.Client
       StatusCode=404
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       InnerException:
```

Response headers:

```
[0]: {[request-id, e459455e-8bba-42b9-89cb-f6eb94f67b64]}
[1]: {[X-CalculatedBETarget, HK2PR02MB0868.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com]}
[2]: {[X-BackEndHttpStatus, 404]}
[3]: {[X-DiagInfo, HK2PR02MB0868]}
[4]: {[X-BEServer, HK2PR02MB0868]}
[5]: {[X-FEServer, AM3PR07CA0025]}
[6]: {[Content-Length, 0]}
[7]: {[Date, Fri, 06 Feb 2015 18:43:12 GMT]}
[8]: {[Set-Cookie, ClientId=5MTQKAN4QEAXMVUEF5DF0W; expires=Sat, 06-Feb-2016 18:43:06 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly]}
[9]: {[Server, Microsoft-IIS/8.0]}
[10]: {[X-Powered-By, ASP.NET]}
```

Comment: Is this the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333362/getting-cannot-resolve-the-odata-request-url-for-specific-users-on-rest-item?

Comment: Not sure. Because that error 400 i got when i made plain requests using Web API HttpClient class, but this time  use Office 365 tools (Office365 c# client library for outlook). Why it gives different status code if it same issue? But yes, it is a failed try to fix that issue.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was the same error or not, that's why I asked :). Can you post the full error response?

Comment: I added more details to the question about error.

Comment: While i was able to sort out this error, the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333362/getting-cannot-resolve-the-odata-request-url-for-specific-users-on-rest-item is still taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simple, as eating an apple...
The reason for this error was a typo in endpoint url.
Bad URI:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/Users('mailbox%40domain.onmicrosoft.com')/Messages('long message id')
```

Better URI:

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('mailbox%40domain.onmicrosoft.com')/Messages('long message id')

Difference - API version was specified.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#MessageoperationsUpdatemessages

Answer (score 0):

Change End Point

replace

**1: https://outlook.office.com/api/beta**

instead of using this

**https://outlook.office365.com/wes/odata**

```
var client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("1url "));
```